# MIDI format in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, audio, midi

I'm finishing a game based on HTML5 and Django. Now I want to add the music to my project. The problem is that the format that I have to use is MIDI, and I haven't found recent information about using this audio format in html5. Does anybody know how I could do this?

Comment: Did you had a look at e.g. https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js. This was just the first result when opening google and typing in the keywords `"midi + js"`. Make sure not to ask questions before you had a look at the topic for your own.